# Don't remove the last one row jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-table, rows

I have this form that fills a table using jQuery, the code works fine the problem is that I don't know how to disable the delete button when I have just one row. I mean I don't want remove the row if is the last one remaining.

Form

```
<form name="prescor" id="prescor" method="post" action="#">
<table class="formulario">
    <tr>
    <td>Cantidad</td>
    <td><input name="cant" type="text" id="cant" autocomplete="off" onKeyUp="subtotal()" pattern="[0-9]*." step="any"></td>
    <td>Artículo</td>
    <td><input name="idarti" type="text" id="idarti" autocomplete="off" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Precio</td>
    <td><input name="prec" id="prec" autocomplete="off" onKeyUp="subtotal()"></td>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td><input name="tota" type="text" id="tota" readonly></td>
    <td><input name="agregar" type="button" value="Agregar" onclick="fn_agregar()" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table id="grilla" class="lista">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Cant.</th>
    <th>Artículo</th>
    <th>Precio</th>
    <th>Subtotal</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><strong>No. Lineas:</strong> <span id="span_cantidad"></span></td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

The script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
fn_eliminar();
fn_cantidad();
});

function fn_cantidad(){
var n = $("#grilla tbody").find("tr").length;
$("#span_cantidad").text(n);
};

function fn_agregar() {
cadena = "<tr>";
cadena = cadena + "<td><input type='text' name='cantidad[]' value='" + $("#cant").val() + "' readonly size='1' required></td>";
cadena = cadena + "<td><input type='text' name='idarticulo[]' value='" + $("#idarti").val() + "' readonly size='2' required></td>";
cadena = cadena + "<td><input type='text' name='precio[]' value='" + $("#prec").val() + "' readonly size='4' required></td>";                                               
cadena = cadena + "<td><input type='text' name='subtotal[]' value='" + $("#tota").val() + "' readonly size='7' required></td>";             
cadena = cadena + "<td><a class='elimina'><img src='cancelar.png' width='16' height='16' title='Eliminar Fila'/></a></td>";
$("#grilla tbody").append(cadena);
document.getElementById("idarti").value="";
document.getElementById("cant").value="";
document.getElementById("prec").value="";
document.getElementById("tota").value="";
fn_eliminar();
fn_cantidad();
};

function fn_eliminar()
{
    $("a.elimina").click(function()
    {
        id = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").eq(0).html();
        $(this).parents("tr").fadeOut("normal", function()
        {
            $(this).remove();
            fn_cantidad();
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the remove handler check whether there is only one item left if so don't do anything.

Also use event delegation to handle the remove element click, In your code you were applying multiple click handlers to the remove element because every time you call `fn_eliminar` it will add a new click handler to all the previously present remove elements

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    fn_eliminar();
    fn_cantidad();
});

function fn_cantidad() {
    var n = $("#grilla tbody").find("tr").length;
    $("#span_cantidad").text(n);
};

function fn_agregar() {
    cadena = "<tr>";
    cadena = cadena + "<td><input type='text' name='cantidad[]' value='" + $("#cant").val() + "' readonly size='1' required></td>";
    cadena = cadena + "<td><input type='text' name='idarticulo[]' value='" + $("#idarti").val() + "' readonly size='2' required></td>";
    cadena = cadena + "<td><input type='text' name='precio[]' value='" + $("#prec").val() + "' readonly size='4' required></td>";
    cadena = cadena + "<td><input type='text' name='subtotal[]' value='" + $("#tota").val() + "' readonly size='7' required></td>";
    cadena = cadena + "<td><a class='elimina'><img src='cancelar.png' width='16' height='16' title='Eliminar Fila'/></a></td>";
    $("#grilla tbody").append(cadena);
    document.getElementById("idarti").value = "";
    document.getElementById("cant").value = "";
    document.getElementById("prec").value = "";
    document.getElementById("tota").value = "";
    fn_cantidad();
};

function fn_eliminar() {
    $("#grilla tbody").on('click', 'a.elimina', function () {
        if ($('#grilla tbody tr').length == 1) {
            return;
        }
        var id = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).html();
        $(this).closest("tr").fadeOut("normal", function () {
            $(this).remove();
            fn_cantidad();
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help the solution was

    if ($("#grilla tbody tr").length > 1){
    $(this).parents("tr").fadeOut("normal", function(){
        $(this).remove();
        fn_cantidad();
    });
    }

Answer (score 0):

You may count the number of rows in the table..

for example,

**HTML**

```
   <table class="invoice-table">
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th>col 1</th>
              <th>col 2</th>
              <th>col 3</th>
              <th>Action</th>
           </tr> 
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
              <td>col 1</td>
              <td>col 2</td>
              <td>col 3</td>
              <td>
               <button type="button" class="remove-row"> DELETE </button>
              </td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove-row', function(){ 
     var rows = $('.invoice-table').find('tbody').children('tr').length;
     if(rows > 1)
     {  
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
     }
     else
     {
        alert("There must be at least one row in the table");
     }
});
```